# Don't display closed discussions on proposal page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, closed-questions

There's a lot of noise already on a proposal page with both comments and discussions by the time a proposal hits commitment phase.

This removes some of the noise which is also distracting for people who are new to our site via recommendations.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea – this was just implemented.